# Css style change depending of value text

Tags: javascript, css, spring, if-statement, thymeleaf

I would like to color the text in the  with 4 different colors depending on the value.
The value scale ranges from 0.0 to 10.0

For example: 0.0 to 2.5 red, 2.6 to 5.0 yellow, 5.1 to 7.5 blue, 7.6 to 10.0 green.

How can I do using javascript?

Be careful that the value within the  is picked up by a Controller.

```html
<span th:text="${value}">1.0</span>
```

If I wanted to use th: classappend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this in Pure Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = foofunc;


function foofunc(){
 var number = document.getElementById("test").value;
 var div = document.getElementById("foo");
  div.style.fontSize = "50px";
  if (number >= 1 && number <= 2.5){
   div.style.color = "Red";
  }
  else if (number >= 2.6 && number <= 5.0){
   div.style.color = "Yellow";
  }
  else if (number >= 5.1 && number <= 7.5){
   div.style.color = "Blue";
  }
  else if (number >= 7.6 && number <= 10){
   div.style.color = "Green";
  }
  else{
   div.style.color = "White";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<input type = "number" id = "test">
<button id = "btn">
change
</button>
<div id = "foo" >1.0</div>
```

Insert value in inputbox, click change, and it will change color according to your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
<c:if test="${value < 2.5}">
<span th:text="${value}" style="color:red">1.0</span>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${value > 2.5 && value < 5.0}">
<span th:text="${value}" style="color:yellow">1.0</span>
</c:if>
```